# Running identical Matlab scripts on multiple local threads

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

- I have a quad-core desktop computer
- I have the Parallel Computing toolbox in Matlab.
- I have a script file that I need to run simultaneously on each core

I'm not sure what the most efficient way to do this is, I know I can create a 'matlabpool' with 4 local workers, but how do I then assign the same script to each one? Or can I use the 'batch' command to run the script on a specific thread, then do that for each one?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a single script using multiple cores using the Parallel Computing toolbox, by using
matlabpool open local 4
and using parfor instead of for loops to execute whatever is in your loop across four threads.   I'm not sure if Parallel Computing toolbox supports running the entirety of the script individually on each core, this will likely not be supported by your hardware.

Comment: What about just calling batch('scriptname') 4 times, will it automatically spread them out on the different cores?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this works, but here is something to try:

When trying to paralelize calculations, they are usually wrapped with something like `parfor`

So I would recommend doing the same with your script, make sure that all required inputs and outputs have the neccesary dimensions and just call:

```
parfor ii = 1:4
   myscript;
end
```

---

Sidenote: Before trying this kind of stuff you may want to check your cpu utilization. If it is already high that means that the inner part of the code uses parallel processing and you should not expect much speedup.